# Convert Java String to Json

Tags: java, java-me, json

I have a list of String which I wish to convert to Json. I am using org\json\me in order to do so. However, I don't know how to continue from here. A little help will be appreciated. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
public class PhoneData implements JSONAble {

    private Display display;   
    private Form mainScr;

    public PhoneData() {   

        mainScr = new Form("Phone Data");
        String imei = IDENInfo.imeiToString(IDENInfo.getIMEI());

        String imsi = new String();
        try{
            imsi=GPRSInfo.imeiToString(SIMCardInfo.getIMSI(), false );           
        }catch(SIMCardException ioe){}   
        String majorOS = DeviceInfo.getPlatformVersion(); 
        int content = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_phone_api"); 
        String version = CodeModuleManager.getModuleVersion(content); //DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion();  
        String modelnumber = DeviceInfo.getDeviceName(); //get modelnumber


        String [] phoneData = new String[] { modelnumber = "Model Number", majorOS = "majorOS", version = "softwareversion"
            ,imei = "imei", imsi = "imsi"};  // an Array

    }


    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        display.setCurrent(mainScr);
        PhoneData user = new PhoneData(); 
    }


    public void fromJSON(String jsonString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public String toJSON() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are your redifining your data inside you array ? are you trying to make a map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to put your data inside a [`Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/java/util/Vector.html), then use the [`new JSONArray(yourvector)`](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/me/JSONArray.java#L147) to make a `JSONArray`.

Comment: I have done Vector vector = new Vector(5, 3);
  vector.addElement(imei);
  vector.addElement(imsi);
  vector.addElement(majorOS);
  vector.addElement(modelnumber);
  vector.addElement(version);

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want to use org.json's barebones package, maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Jettison driver with XStream to serialize / deserialize string <-> json : 
http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

I had used this sometime back - there are some caveats on how the json schema should be for the parser to parse perfectly well.

Comment: Will this be very different from using org\json\me?

Comment: Sorry. I've not used org.json.me.*.